# Completely disable paste option in CKeditor web page form

Tags: php, codeigniter, ckeditor

I have not been able to disable paste(CTRL+V) option in CKeditor. Although right click paste option is disabled now.

Below is config.js file for CKeditor

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
config.extraPlugins = 'wordcount,notification';

config.wordcount = {

    // Whether or not you want to show the Paragraphs Count
    showParagraphs: false,

    // Whether or not you want to show the Word Count
    showWordCount: true,

    // Whether or not you want to show the Char Count
    showCharCount: true,

    // Whether or not you want to count Spaces as Chars
    countSpacesAsChars: true,

    // Whether or not to include Html chars in the Char Count
    countHTML: false,

    // Maximum allowed Word Count, -1 is default for unlimited
    maxWordCount: -1,

    // Maximum allowed Char Count, -1 is default for unlimited
    maxCharCount: 2000
};
// The toolbar groups arrangement, optimized for a single toolbar row.
config.toolbarGroups = [
    { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
    { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
    { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
    { name: 'forms' },
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ] },
    { name: 'links' },
    { name: 'insert' },
    { name: 'styles' },
    { name: 'colors' },
    { name: 'tools' },
    { name: 'others' },
    { name: 'about' }
];
CKEDITOR.config.toolbar = [
   ['Format','FontSize'],

   ['Bold','Italic','Underline','StrikeThrough','-','Undo','Redo','-','Cut','Copy','Paste','Find','Replace','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Print'],

   ['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],
   ['-','Link']
] ;
// The default plugins included in the basic setup define some buttons that
// are not needed in a basic editor. They are removed here.
config.removeButtons = 'Cut,Copy,Paste,Undo,Redo,Anchor,Underline,Strike,Subscript,Superscript';

// Dialog windows are also simplified.
config.removeDialogTabs = 'link:advanced';
```

};

[This is how the editor looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqBrj.png)

Controller function loading this editor is-

```
public function edit_cv(){
$user_id= $this->CI->session->userdata('id');
$this->addJS("tnpcell/edit.js");
$this->addJS("ckeditor/ckeditor.js");
$this->addJS("ckeditor/samples/js/sample.js");
$data['cv_data'] = $this->cv_model->get_achievements($user_id);
foreach ($data['cv_data'] as $row){
      $row->editor_content = urldecode($row->editor_content);
      $row->skype_id = urldecode($row->skype_id);
      $row->shoe_size = urldecode($row->shoe_size);
      $row->blood_group = urldecode($row->blood_group);
      $row->specialization = urldecode($row->specialization);
      $row->editor_content = str_replace('$.ol.$', '<ol>', $row->editor_content);
      $row->editor_content = str_replace('$.ul.$', '<ul>', $row->editor_content);
      $row->editor_content = str_replace('$.li.$', '<li>', $row->editor_content);
      $row->editor_content = str_replace('$./ol.$', '</ol>', $row->editor_content);
      $row->editor_content = str_replace('$./ul.$', '</ul>', $row->editor_content);
      $row->editor_content = str_replace('$./li.$', '</li>', $row->editor_content);
      $row->editor_content = str_replace('$.nbsp.$', '&nbsp;', $row->editor_content);
}
$data['project_data'] = $this->cv_model->get_project($user_id);
foreach ($data['project_data'] as $row) {
      $row->title = urldecode($row->title);
      $row->role = urldecode($row->role);
}
$this->load->model('course_structure/basic_model','',TRUE);
$this->load->model('student/student_academic_model','',TRUE);
$data['student_academic']=$this->student_academic_model->get_stu_academic_details_by_id($user_id);
$data['branch_name']=$this->basic_model->get_branch_details_by_id($data['student_academic']->branch_id)[0]->name;

$this->drawHeader("Edit Your CV");
$this->load->view('tnpcell/edit_cv',$data);
$this->drawFooter();
```

}

I want user should not be able to paste any text in the field of editor (as shown  in picture above). But currently pasting some text using ctrl+V is enabled.

Comment: Dont expect help for a one-liner question, which shows no effort at all. What have you tried, where is your code, etc?

Comment: Actually its bit complex code. Uploading all used code for this editor is not possible. However, now I have shared few.

Answer (score 3):

You can cancel the [paste](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-paste) event.

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.on('paste', function(evt) {
    evt.cancel();
});
```

Comment: Do I need to write this in the controller which is loading the editor?

Comment: I don't know how to use it in your controller, because not enough info is provided. It is pure JavaScript and it has to be called after CKEditor instance initializes, so you can use its instance name. I used `editor1` just for this demo.